# Wordpress adding subdirectory to permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Looking into our Google Analytics it seems some people are visiting pages on our site with the wrong permalink. Specifically WP is adding an extra directory on the end for some reason.

`www.mysite.com/contact/`  <- Correct

`www.mysite.com/mysite/contact/` <- Incorrect (some people ending up here)

It seems every page on the site has this problem (some people ending up at `/mysite/page/` instead of just `/page/`

It's a standard WP install (not in a subdirectory), the permalink structure is set as follows:

`www.mysite.com/blog/%postname%/`

Looking in GA, all the visitors from the wrong permalink are coming from the source/medium of direct/none.

I've ran a URL checker on the site and everything is coming up as 200 OK with none of the wrong permalinks showing anywhere.

Would appreciate any ideas here, pretty stumped on this one! Only thought I have is that maybe it's something to do with the database containing wrong links as my localhost install was `localhost:8888/mysite/`.

Thanks, Adam

Comment: have a look at your .htaccess file

Comment: and search the database in phpmyadmin!!

Comment: have you recently migrated your website? Did you try to flush the permalinks and create them again?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can rewrite permalinks with help srdb

search: `localhost:8888/mysite` 
replace: `www.mysite.com`

with `http://`

Before doing a copy of the database

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. After considerable digging it turns out GA was logging visits from my local version of the site. Have resolved now.